# Ruby 1.9 - invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ascii

Im trying to make my rails application (2.3.5) to run on Ruby 1.9, I've this function that make some transformations on a string:

```
def replace_special_chars(downcase = true)
if downcase 
  string = self.downcase
else
  string = self
end
string.gsub! /á|ã|à|ä|â/, 'a'
string.gsub! /é|è|ë|ê/, 'e'
string.gsub! /í|ì|ï|î/, 'i'
string.gsub! /ó|õ|ò|ô|ö/, 'o'
string.gsub! /ú|ù|ü|û/, 'u'
string.gsub! /ç/, 'c'
string.gsub! /&/, 'e'
string.gsub! /\s/, '-'
string.gsub! /[^a-zA-Z_0-9-]/, ''
string.gsub! /-(-)+/, '-'
string
end
```

But when I try to start the server, I got this error:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require':   
/Users/.../lib/nzn_string.rb:11: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) (SyntaxError)
/Users/.../lib/nzn_string.rb:11: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) 
/Users/.../lib/nzn_string.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
string.gsub! /á|ã|à|ä|â/, 'a'
                ^
```

from :29:in `require'

What's the right way to do this on ruby 1.9?
I don't know what im missing here

Comment: possible duplicate of [invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) with Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739836/invalid-multibyte-char-us-ascii-with-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: This link is helpful and it works for me

[Stackoverflow answer]


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916931/rails-3-invalid-multibyte-char-us-ascii?s=bed697c0-32eb-47d0-a22a-3b85ee418b0f#new-answer

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Write `# encoding: utf-8` on top of that file. That changes the default encoding of all string/regexp  literals in that file `utf-8`. The default encoding for all literals is `US-ASCII`, which cannot represent `á`.

Comment: hey. that worked, thank you. Is there a way to make this project wide?

Comment: @Tiago: Yes: Add that line to all files in your project.

Comment: If the target script runs standalone, the encoding line is second from the top:

`#!/usr/bin/env ruby`
`# encoding: utf-8`

`require 'abc'`
`...`

Answer (score 3):

To make it project-wide, try: the [magic_encoding](https://github.com/m-ryan/magic_encoding) gem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also change the regexps from the syntax /re/ to the syntax (Regexp.new 're', nil, 'n')

For example, the instruction you mentioned:

string.gsub! /á|ã|à|ä|â/, 'a'

will become:

string.gsub! (Regexp.new 'á|ã|à|ä|â', nil, 'n'), 'a'

More details here:

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/183413