# Rails 3 invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, ascii, ruby-1.9

I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739836/invalid-multibyte-char-us-ascii-with-ruby-on-rails) but I can't solve the problem anyway.

I got this

```
/home/fra/siti/Pensiero/db/seeds.rb:32: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/home/fra/siti/Pensiero/db/seeds.rb:32: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/home/fra/siti/Pensiero/db/seeds.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
... ed il valore della vita, si è malati", :user_id => 1, :cat...
```

The problem is in this string

```
:body => "Nel momento in cui ci si chiede il significato ed il valore della vita, si è malati"
```

I got the problem with every "e" character with the accent, like "è é "

I tried to put magic comment `# coding: utf-8` but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: ruby 1.9.2p0, rails 3.0.0, i'm using rvm

Comment: Rails should do that, but could you please check if $KCODE == 'utf-8'?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678172/ruby-1-9-invalid-multibyte-char-us-ascii/3678204#3678204

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2105210/1028100

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Instead of adding `# coding: UTF-8` try to add `# encoding: UTF-8` on the first line of the file.

It worked for me. I found the information here : http://groups.google.com/group/sinatrarb/browse_thread/thread/f92529bf0cf62015

Answer (score 10):

Just add the following line as the first line in the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 6):

Add a magic comment in the script where you use non-ascii chars? It should go on top of the script.

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

It worked for me like charm.

Or if you want to make the project wide, you have an option of [magic-encoding](https://github.com/m-ryan/magic_encoding) gem

Answer (score 1):

I changed the line:

```
gem 'pdf-writer', :git => 'git://github.com/metaskills/pdf-writer.git'
```

and that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from http://devsolvd.com/questions/rails-3-invalid-multibyte-char-us-ascii

```
gem 'pdf-writer', :git => 'git://github.com/metaskills/pdf-writer.git'
```

This was useful for me