# rake db:seed for i18n data

Tags: rake

I am running rake db:seed to populate i18n data in the database but it doesn't recognize the i18n characters. The error that I get is --

rake aborted!

$HOME/db/seeds.rb:9: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)

$HOME/db/seeds.rb:9: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)

$HOME/db/seeds.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting '}'

Do I need to convert the native language strings into UTF-8 characters before calling the rake?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916931/rails-3-invalid-multibyte-char-us-ascii fixed it

Answer (score 5):

Just add the following line as the first line of your *seeds.rb* the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

**UPDATE:**
In ruby 2.0 (and seems above) you don't need to do this anymore, `utf-8` is now being the default encoding.