# Global settings to solve invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, character-encoding

My problem is simillar to [Rails 3 invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916931)

Solution, presented there does works, but i find this a little goofy to include comment **# encoding: UTF-8** to every file, that uses non ASCII characters.

In config/application.rb, i have following option:

```
# Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

But, it does't helps.

Maybe, some another global configuration option is presented exactly for such cases ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to default Ruby 1.9 to use UTF-8 for all source files (and yes, it's a huge PITA).

The `config.encoding` setting is telling Rails something, nothing to do with Ruby.

The best *solution* I've come up with relies on something that I haven't seen mentioned.  There's another way to get Ruby 1.9 to see a file as UTF-8, instad of using that magic comment you can include the UTF-8 [BOM (Byte Order Marker)](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark) in your file.  Ruby 1.9 will do the right thing.

Now to the cool part - I use gvim, and it's actually very simple to configure gvim to put a BOM into every file that should have one.  It's as simple as adding this to my `.vimrc`:

```
set bomb
```

Not sure if you're using gvim, or if other editors can do this.  So obviously YMMV :)

Comment: Just to clarify "config.encoding setting is telling Rails something" as I was curious myself. It seems to set Encoding.default_external and Encoding.default_internal - at least this is what I found when I looked at the source of the encoding setter at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application/Configuration.html#method-i-encoding-3D

Comment: Yes, what I really meant was that this will affect the files that your app interacts with, but it won't affect how Ruby loads the source files themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the environment variable `RUBYOPT=-Ku` when running the application, and it will make ruby (even 1.9) assume utf-8 encoding for all `.rb` source files.

For a rails app though, I would rather recommend not using that trick, and instead put your non-ascii parts in the i18n files and referencing them through `I18n.t`.

It's a bit more tedious to set up if you've already got your application up and running, but should you ever need to translate it into another language you're already halfway there.

Answer (score -1):

You can set this in your application.rb file if you are actually coding multibyte characters directly in your templates.

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

This is the equivalent of putting:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

at the top of every file.

Comment: AFAIK, this is the same as setting config.encoding = "utf-8"

Comment: That's not true. UTF symbols in source files will still cause that exception.