# ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII): in ruby upgrade 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.0.3 in my application.while uploading any files  i am getting following error in production

ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII):

config/initializers/rake_multipart.rb:35:in `=~'
config/initializers/rake_multipart.rb:35:in`block in parse_multipart'
config/initializers/rake_multipart.rb:30:in `loop'
config/initializers/rake_multipart.rb:30:in`parse_multipart'

Comment: Show `rake_multipart.rb` file.

Comment: May be it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916931/rails-3-invalid-multibyte-char-us-ascii/9528543#9528543

Answer (score 0):

If you are on macOS or Linux, you can start Middleman this way to force it to use UTF-8:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 middleman
```

Not sure about Windows, though.