# How can I allow these characters to be saved in Postgresql using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, utf-8, import

I am writing an import routine for Geonames.  One of the columns has what I am assuming is full UTF-8 characters (Chinese, English, etc).

Anyway, it's crashing on a few characters.  Mainly:  `”` (please don't confuse with `"`).

Here is my code:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "geo_cities"
end

class Cities
    class << self
        def parse(file)
            File.new(file).each_line do |line|
                s = line.chomp.split("\t")
                city = City.new

                # remove ” and "
                alternatenames = s[3].gsub(/\"/, "")
                alternatenames = alternatenames.gsub("”", "")
                alternatenames = '{' + alternatenames.split(/,/).map {|n| '"' + n + '"'}.join(",") + '}'

                city.geonameid          = s[0]
                city.name               = s[1]
                city.asciiname          = s[2]
                city.alternatenames     = alternatenames
                city.latitude           = s[4]
                city.longitude          = s[5]
                city.featureclass       = s[6]
                city.featurecode        = s[7]
                city.countrycode        = s[8]
                # city.cc2                = "{#{s[9]}}"
                city.admin1code         = s[10]
                city.admin2code         = s[11]
                city.admin3code         = s[12]
                city.admin4code         = s[13]
                city.population         = s[14]
                city.elevation          = s[15]
                city.dem                = s[16]
                city.timezone           = s[17]
                city.modificationdate   = Time.parse(s[18])

                yield city
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I really don't line the way I use gsub to try and prevent the import from breaking.  Most seem to work OK but the quotes (and the closed quote) is crashing it.

Here is the error:

```
invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) (SyntaxError)
/Users/cbmeeks/Dropbox/Projects/flockgeo/geonames/imports/models.rb:38: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/Users/cbmeeks/Dropbox/Projects/flockgeo/geonames/imports/models.rb:38: syntax error,     unexpected $end, expecting ')'
            alternatenames = alternatenames.gsub("”", "")
                                                    ^
```

This is going into a Postgresql database, btw.

Any pointers on how to clean this up?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby 1.9 - invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678172/ruby-1-9-invalid-multibyte-char-us-ascii)

Comment: Yes, the answer on that question solved this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the multibyte char seemed to work, I also had an error in my gsub.  This is what allowed all 122k records to be imported:

```
s[3].gsub! 34.chr, ''
```