# add special characters regex ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have this regex in my model:

```
/^(?:[^\W_]|\s|[\._@-])*$/u
```

I want add to this regex this special char:

```
ñáéíóú
```

I would like to know how add other charset from other languajes, chino, japanesse, indian...etc. Thank you.

Comment: Could you give some examples of what you want to match and what you don't?

Comment: e.g, I want match words like "España", "olé"...etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if Ruby understand that, but you should use unicode properties like:

```
/^[\p{L}\s\p{N}._@?¿!¡€-]+$/
```

where

```
\p{L}   : any unicode letter
\p{N}   : any unicode number
```

Comment: Yes works fine :D. Its possible add to this regex this characters **?¿!¡€,** Thank youuu!

Comment: I get error  **invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)** with this regex :( `/^[\p{L}\s\p{N}._@?¿!¡€-]+$/`

Comment: @hyperrjas: I don't know Ruby but I've found that :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739836/invalid-multibyte-char-us-ascii-with-rails-and-ruby-1-9

Comment: Wooow Thank you now it does works fine :D write `# encoding: utf-8` and works fine :D Thank you  @M42 and @apneadiving