# ruby magic encoding not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding

I have a rails application and i keep getting this error

```
  /srv/projects/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:174: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) /srv/projects/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:174: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) /srv/projects/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:174: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')' ...e_title = h("#{project_name} — #{name || translate_locatio... ... ^
```

and the fix should be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739836/invalid-multibyte-char-us-ascii-with-rails-and-ruby-1-9) but when i added the line on top of my application controller i still get the error...i even restarted apache

Here is my application controller

```
# Filters added to this controller apply to all controllers in the application.
# Likewise, all the methods added will be available for all controllers.

# encoding: utf-8


class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# encoding: utf-8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding comment must be on top of the file before anything else - including other comments (except the shebang if you have one).

Answer (score 1):

Your class should look like this:

```
# encoding: utf-8
# Filters added to this controller apply to all controllers in the application.
# Likewise, all the methods added will be available for all controllers.

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```

(with the magic comment at the top)