# Compass (ruby) encoding error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, compass-sass

I had Compass 0.12 (a ruby gem) installed on Ubuntu Oneiric with no problems I have updated to Precise formatting / and keeping /home, so I needed to reinstall ruby (1.9.3).

I get this error now when I compile a SCSS file:

```
compass watch --trace

            Change detected at 12:45:09 to: style.scss overwrite css/style.css

Dear developers making use of FSSM in your projects, FSSM is essentially dead at this point. Further development will be taking place in the new shared guard/listen project. Please let us know if you need help transitioning! ^_^b - Travis Tilley

>>> Compass is polling for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
ArgumentError on line ["46"] of /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb:46:in `chop_basename'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb:102:in `cleanpath_aggressive'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb:90:in `cleanpath'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb:452:in `relative_path_from'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/path.rb:82:in `split_path'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/path.rb:70:in `run_callback'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/path.rb:56:in `callback_action'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/path.rb:36:in `update'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:39:in `block in modified'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:37:in `each'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:37:in `modified'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:18:in `refresh'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in run'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:17:in `each'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:17:in `block in run'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:15:in `loop'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:15:in `run'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/monitor.rb:26:in `run'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm.rb:70:in `monitor'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:89:in `perform'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/bin/compass:29:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/bin/compass:43:in `call'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/bin/compass:43:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/bin/compass:19:in `load'
  /usr/local/bin/compass:19:in `<main>'
```

(The "Dear developers" message is part of the output).

This error doesn't appear the first time I make a change to the scss file, but the second.

In addition, compass "eats" one "s" in some files and, instead of compiling them as "style.css" (what it should be from the file's name) it does as "tyle.css".

I've spend 3 hours looking at similar problems here but I couldn't solve it. I tried including # encoding: utf-8 on the top of some files with no luck.

Please explain step by step what should I do, since I am a total noob with Ruby (I just use it because of SASS).

Comment: Does the full path contain any non-ascii bytes?

Comment: The full path to the compass project does, to the lib doesn't. It was like that before and it worked :S

Comment: what is the path of the compass project folder? maybe it has some non-ASCII character

Comment: All my projects have this path: /home/username/Público/Proyectos/projectname

The path was exactly like that in Ubuntu 11.10 and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is some problem with the pathname, maybe it contains an invalid non-ASCII sequence; probably the eaten "s" is the problem, maybe it is an invalid character, or maybe a character near to it; try to ensure path is ASCII.

Or maybe a bug in precise readline package? Try to install ruby 1.9.3 via RVM, RVM should use readline bundled with it (see the comments below for details)

Comment: Since the path was the same before the update, what could have changed?

Comment: was the folder "Público" the same? it contains a non-ASCII character, try to copy the project to a folder with an ASCII path... just guessing, I've never had this error

Comment: It was the same, so the problem is not there. It must be related with what has changed, not with what has't changed.

Comment: The problem should be in the pathname: so the error log says, and this is confirmed by your eaten s too. Maybe a bug in precise readline package? Try to install ruby 1.9.3 via RVM, RVM should use readline bundled with it... again, just guessing

Comment: I put the project in a folder other than "Público" and it works. But again, I don't get why it worked with that path before and it doesn't do now.

Comment: It worked after installing via RVM (which was a bit scary :P). Can you please put your comment as an answer, to mark it as correct?

Comment: I guess it is a problem related to Ubuntu readline library, it is bugged one time yes and one time not :)

Comment: Please post your comment (Try to install ruby 1.9.3 via RVM, RVM should use readline bundled with it) as an answer to mark it as valid.

Comment: I edited the answer, so there should be no need to ad another answer, I think

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, the file in question `pathname.rb` contains this function that seems to be where the trouble is:

```
def chop_basename(path)
  base = File.basename(path)
  if /\A#{SEPARATOR_PAT}?\z/o =~ base
    return nil
  else
    return path[0, path.rindex(base)], base
  end
end
private :chop_basename
```

Here's a link to a similar question with the same issue:

[Ruby on Rails application won’t start using Passenger when there are non-ASCII characters in the app path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175975/ruby-on-rails-application-wont-start-using-passenger-when-there-are-non-ascii-c)

So the fix is clearly to stick with us-ascii pathnames.

Here's a snippet from the doc on that class:

> Pathname represents a pathname which locates a file in a filesystem. The pathname depends on OS: Unix, Windows, etc. Pathname library works with pathnames of local OS. However non-Unix pathnames are supported experimentally.

As to why it worked before and doesn't now, that's hard to say. It's possible that some other library on your system changed, or that the upgrade to ruby 1.9.3 caused a minor change that introduced the error.