# Can't install compass via rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm, compass-sass

I was a happy and worries-free user of compass in Ubuntu 11.10. I upgraded to 12.04 and got this problem: [Compass (ruby) encoding error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495908/compass-ruby-encoding-error)

I somehow managed to solve it installing ruby via rvm on one of my computers but now I get a different error in my other computer (which had the same initial problem). I install ruby and compass and use the global gemset as default:

```
    gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.1.3)
chunky_png (1.2.5)
compass (0.12.1)
fssm (0.2.9)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.0)
rvm (1.11.3.3)
sass (3.1.18)
```

But when I try to do anything with compass, I get this error:

```
    compass
/home/mrpotato/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:22:in `default_gemfile': Could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
    from /home/mrpotato/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:213:in `default_gemfile'
    from /home/mrpotato/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:164:in `root'
    from /home/mrpotato/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:123:in `load'
    from /home/mrpotato/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `setup'
    from /home/mrpotato/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from /home/mrpotato/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/compass-0.12.1/bin/compass:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mrpotato/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/compass:19:in `load'
    from /home/mrpotato/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/compass:19:in `<main>'
    from /home/mrpotato/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /home/mrpotato/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears to be a problem with the new version of rubygems-bundler that was just released. Installing the previous version (`gem install -v 0.9.2 rubygems-bundler`) fixed it for me.

Edit: I also ran `rubygems-bundler-uninstaller` which may have been the real source of the fix.

Comment: this is a bug in **compass**, I have fixed it here https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/pull/894 - waiting for it being merged, this is only temporary solution.

Comment: Confirming that running `rubygems-bundler-uninstaller` worked for me also.

Comment: Also confirming - but on osx lion.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem today when trying to install Compass/SASS/RVM on a mac with Mountain Lion.

I couldn't get rubygems-bundler-uninstaller to run/uninstall, so I had to do the following:

1. Switch to the rvm global gemset and uninstall rubygems-bundler
   rvm ruby-1.9.3-p194@global then gem uninstall rubygems-bundler
2. Then switch back to my other gemset - rvm ruby-1.9.3-p194 and now running compass or sass or whatever gem works

Not sure if it is the correct way of doing things, but it worked for me.  Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

it's a bug in **compass** it assumes that existence of `Bundler` means `Bundler.setup` was called.

Here are the lines that break it https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/blob/stable/bin/compass#L24-L26:

```
24 if defined?(Bundler)
25   Bundler.require :assets
26 end
```

Comment: Do I need bundler for using Compass or can I simply uninstall it?

Comment: You need `bundler` to handle `Gemfile` - if you do not it - drop this file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using yeoman for building a node-based app that just happens to want to use compass, you can disable the Gemfile requirement for these types of apps.

Just add this line to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export NOEXEC_EXCLUDE="compass"
```

Run `source ~/.bash_profile` and try it again. I was having this issue when running `grunt server` on a yeoman-generated angular project (which doesn't need a Gemfile).

https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler#disabling-executables