# Compass gem throwing error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to get started with Compass & Sass. I've installed the compass gem with three versions of ruby (1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3) and each time I get the same error:

```
martin@crunchbang:~$ compass
/home/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:22:in `default_gemfile': Could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
    from /home/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:213:in `default_gemfile'
    from /home/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:164:in `root'
    from /home/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:123:in `load'
    from /home/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `setup'
    from /home/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from /home/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/compass-0.12.1/bin/compass:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/compass:19:in `load'
    from /home/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/compass:19:in `<main>'
    from /home/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /home/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610254/cant-install-compass-via-rvm), there seems to be some sort of issue with the compass gem and the new version of bundler.

To resolve just run:

```
rubygems-bundler-uninstaller
```