# Compass gemfile syntax error on Ubuntu 12.10, Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, compass-sass

Having run the standard procedure for installing the rvm, which also installs Ruby 1.9.3, then installing gems for rake, compass, sass, bundler and guard, then adding my gems/bin directory to my path I get the following message on running compass:

```
/home/m1ke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:35:in `rescue in eval_gemfile': Gemfile syntax error: (Bundler::GemfileError)
gem "guard", "~> 1.0.1"
                    ^
from /home/m1ke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:32:in `eval_gemfile'
from /home/m1ke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in     from /home/m1ke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:18:in `build'
from /home/m1ke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:144:in `definition'
from /home/m1ke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:112:in `setup'
from /home/m1ke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
from /home/m1ke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:26:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/m1ke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/compass:19:in `load'
from /home/m1ke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/compass:19:in `<main>
from /home/m1ke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /home/m1ke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

All gems were installed with the standard `gem install compass` syntax, I have also run `gem  update --system`

More information!

- The same gem works fine on my Windows install, installed using the Windows RubyInstaller.
- Having had no responses I tried removing the gem and installing the ruby-compass package from `apt-get`. This works fine, but now another gem (not available on apt-get) reports errors the come from both `/home/m1ke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.9-p362/` but also from `/usr/share/ruby-1.9.1/` which I assume the Compass apt-get installed. So now I may have two Ruby versions fighting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610254/cant-install-compass-via-rvm)

Just run `rubygems-bundler-uninstaller` and the problem was fixed right away. Posting this here instead of just linking as the thread linked didn't come up when I searched my error, as my error was a syntax error whereas the linked post has a "file not found" error.