# Gemfile syntax error on bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redmine

NB: This is not the same problem asked in [Compass gemfile syntax error on Ubuntu 12.10, Ruby 1.9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236388/compass-gemfile-syntax-error-on-ubuntu-12-10-ruby-1-9-3)

I've set up a turnkeylinux redmine machine, and upgraded it to the latest version of Redmine. At various stages I've needed to `bundle update` a few times, and it's worked fine.

I installed a couple of plugins and themes, ran the various rake upgrade scripts, and left the install working. A few hours later, it was giving Passenger errors, and when I try to install a missing gemfile using bundle install, I get the message

```
Bundler::GemfileError: Gemfile syntax error:
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:33:in `rescue in eval_gemfile'                                                                      
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:29:in `eval_gemfile'                                                                                
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:9:in `evaluate'                                                                                     
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:19:in `build'                                                                                
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'                                                                                     
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:245:in `install'                                                                                    
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'                                                                            
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-    1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'                                                             
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'                                                                           
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'                                                                         
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'                                                                           
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'                                                             
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                    
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'                                                                                                                            
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

I've been through various suggestions on forums, none of which has helped - despite the question referenced above having similar symptoms. One solution is adding `require 'yaml'` at the top rather than halfway down - also no joy.

Running `ruby -c Gemfile` returns no syntax errors, so I'm guessing it's not really a syntax error - but I'd be happy to be wrong. Renaming the Gemfile.lock file doesn't help.

Can anyone shed any light? Gemfile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'                                                                                                                                 

require 'yaml'                                                                                                                                                

gem "rails", "3.2.21"                                                                                                                                         
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 3.1.1"                                                                                                                                
gem "coderay", "~> 1.1.0"                                                                                                                                     
gem "fastercsv", "~> 1.5.0", :platforms => [:mri_18, :mingw_18, :jruby]                                                                                       
gem "builder", ">= 3.0.4"                                                                                                                                     
gem "request_store", "1.0.5"                                                                                                                                  
gem "mime-types"                                                                                                                                              
gem "rbpdf", "~> 1.18.5"                                                                                                                                      

gem "i18n", "~> 0.6.11"                                                                                                                                       

# Optional gem for LDAP authentication                                                                                                                        
#group :ldap do                                                                                                                                               
#  gem "net-ldap", "~> 0.3.1"                                                                                                                                 
#end                                                                                                                                                          

# Optional gem for OpenID authentication                                                                                                                      
#group :openid do                                                                                                                                             
#  gem "ruby-openid", "~> 2.3.0", :require => "openid"                                                                                                        
#  gem "rack-openid"                                                                                                                                          
#end                                                                                                                                                          

platforms :mri, :mingw do                                                                                                                                     
  # Optional gem for exporting the gantt to a PNG file, not supported with jruby                                                                              
  group :rmagick do                                                                                                                                           
    # RMagick 2 supports ruby 1.9                                                                                                                             
    # RMagick 1 would be fine for ruby 1.8 but Bundler does not support                                                                                       
    # different requirements for the same gem on different platforms                                                                                          
    gem "rmagick", (RUBY_VERSION < "1.9" ? "2.13.3" : "~> 2.13.4")                                                                                            
  end                                                                                                                                                         

  # Optional Markdown support, not for JRuby                                                                                                                  
  group :markdown do                                                                                                                                          
    # TODO: upgrade to redcarpet 3.x when ruby1.8 support is dropped                                                                                          
    gem "redcarpet", "~> 2.3.0"                                                                                                                               
  end                                                                                                                                                         
end                                                                                                                                                           

platforms :jruby do                                                                                                                                           
  # jruby-openssl is bundled with JRuby 1.7.0                                                                                                                 
  gem "jruby-openssl" if Object.const_defined?(:JRUBY_VERSION) && JRUBY_VERSION < '1.7.0'                                                                     
  gem "activerecord-jdbc-adapter", "~> 1.3.2"                                                                                                                 
end                                                                                                                                                           

# Include database gems for the adapters found in the database                                                                                                
# configuration file                                                                                                                                          
require 'erb'                                                                                                                                                 
require 'yaml'                                                                                                                                                
database_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "config/database.yml")                                                                                      
if File.exist?(database_file)                                                                                                                                 
  database_config = YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(database_file)).result)                                                                                        
  adapters = database_config.values.map {|c| c['adapter']}.compact.uniq                                                                                       
  if adapters.any?                                                                                                                                            
    adapters.each do |adapter|                                                                                                                                
      case adapter                                                                                                                                            
      when 'mysql2'                                                                                                                                           
        gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]                                                                                               
        gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby                                                                                            
      when 'mysql'                                                                                                                                            
        gem "mysql", "~> 2.8.1", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]                                                                                                 
        gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby                                                                                            
      when /postgresql/                                                                                                                                       
        gem "pg", "~> 0.17.1", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]                                                                                                   
        gem "activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby                                                                                       
      when /sqlite3/                                                                                                                                          
        gem "sqlite3", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]                                                                                                           
        gem "jdbc-sqlite3", "< 3.8", :platforms => :jruby                                                                                                     
        gem "activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter", :platforms => :jruby                                                                                          
      when /sqlserver/                                                                                                                                        
        gem "tiny_tds", "~> 0.6.2", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]                                                                                              
        gem "activerecord-sqlserver-adapter", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]                                                                                    
      else                                                                                                                                                    
        warn("Unknown database adapter `#{adapter}` found in config/database.yml, use Gemfile.local to load your own database gems")                          
      end                                                                                                                                                     
    end                                                                                                                                                       
  else                                                                                                                                                        
    warn("No adapter found in config/database.yml, please configure it first")                                                                                
  end                                                                                                                                                         
else                                                                                                                                                          
  warn("Please configure your config/database.yml first")                                                                                                     
end                                                                                                                                                           

group :development do                                                                                                                                         
  gem "rdoc", ">= 2.4.2"                                                                                                                                      
  gem "yard"                                                                                                                                                  
end                                                                                                                                                           

group :test do                                                                                                                                                
  gem "minitest"                                                                                                                                              
  gem "test-unit", "~> 3.0"                                                                                                                                   
  gem "shoulda", "~> 3.3.2"                                                                                                                                   
  gem "shoulda-matchers", "1.4.1"                                                                                                                             
  gem "mocha", "~> 1.0.0", :require => 'mocha/api'                                                                                                            
  if RUBY_VERSION >= '1.9.3'                                                                                                                                  
    gem "capybara"                                                                                                                                            
    gem "selenium-webdriver"                                                                                                                                  
  end                                                                                                                                                         
end                                                                                                                                                           

local_gemfile = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "Gemfile.local")                                                                                            
if File.exists?(local_gemfile)                                                                                                                                
  puts "Loading Gemfile.local ..." if $DEBUG # `ruby -d` or `bundle -v`                                                                                       
  instance_eval File.read(local_gemfile)                                                                                                                      
end                                                                                                                                                           

# Load plugins' Gemfiles                                                                                                                                      
Dir.glob File.expand_path("../plugins/*/{Gemfile,PluginGemfile}", __FILE__) do |file|                                                                         
  puts "Loading #{file} ..." if $DEBUG # `ruby -d` or `bundle -v`                                                                                             
  #TODO: switch to "eval_gemfile file" when bundler >= 1.2.0 will be required (rails 4)                                                                       
  instance_eval File.read(file), file                                                                                                                         
end
```

Comment: Is it a problem that you have `require yaml` twice?  Other than that, I would recommend running `git diff`, rolling back to a stable version and gradually adding changes back to isolate the issue.

Comment: Maybe you have a syntax error in one of the other gemfiles you eval.

Comment: Both @steveklein and @smathy make good points. The other thing you could try is to `require 'byebug'; debugger` at the top of your file and step through to figure out where it dies. I have no idea if that will work for something that's getting eval'ed like this is, but worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. They go a little beyond my familiarity with linux shell & ruby, so I think I'm going to have to go back to a previous VM snapshot and try the upgrade again with more snapshots along the way.