# Compass throwing error on update to Mavericks

Tags: ruby, bundler, compass-sass, osx-mavericks

After upgrading to Mavericks OS compass throws an error whenever I try to create anything. It seems like from some other errors that it may have to do with the bundler, but I have tried un-installing and installing different versions -- none of this worked for me. Any other ideas?

```
KBD$ compass create test
/Users/KBD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:16:in `build': /Gemfile not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
    from /Users/KBD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
    from /Users/KBD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
    from /Users/KBD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/KBD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:26:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/KBD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/compass:23:in `load'
    from /Users/KBD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/KBD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/KBD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: That command worked fine for me; maybe it's a version issue? Here's my info: `ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]` and  `Compass 0.12.2 (Alnilam)`

Comment: @sherb I'm on Ruby 2.0, which seems like it could be the culprit. It's basically the only thing I haven't messed with because I would rather find a fix and be able to stay on Ruby 2.0, if possible.

Comment: Hunter, [RVM](https://rvm.io/) may be a good option for you. I'm using ruby 1.9 because Sencha Cmd has problems with 2.0. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so it did seem to end up having to do with the bundler. I finally got it uninstalled and that seems to have fixed the problem. This similar question/answer helped.

[Can't install compass via rvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610254/cant-install-compass-via-rvm?rq=1)

I hope this helps. I just ran gem uninstall rubygems-bundler, and uninstalled all.