# Problems with accents in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem with accents inside of instance variables in rails 3

controller

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tutor="Uriel Hernández"
  end
end
```

view

```
<h1>Bienvenido al curso de Ruby on Rails 3</h1>
<h2>Tutor: <%=@tutor  %></h2>
<p>Esta es mi primera vista</p>
```

Browser

```
 SyntaxError in WelcomeController#index

/home/fernando/codigofacilito/helloworld/hello_world/app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:3: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/home/fernando/codigofacilito/helloworld/hello_world/app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:3: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/home/fernando/codigofacilito/helloworld/hello_world/app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
    @tutor="Uriel Hernández"
                        ^
Rails.root: /home/fernando/codigofacilito/helloworld/hello_world
```

Comment: just add as a comment `# encoding: UTF-8` at the very first line of your file(s) containing at least one accent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Ruby are you running?

You might need to specify the `#encoding` directive at the top of your file.

See: [invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) with Rails and Ruby 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739836/invalid-multibyte-char-us-ascii-with-rails-and-ruby-1-9)

Comment: This answer should be a comment instead (and a duplicate close vote as it has been asked about a thousand times already).