# Deploying a Ruby application on Passenger + Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I am trying to run a rails application on Apache2. When viewing the site on the browser it list all the files in the directory instead of running the application. The error log for Apache shows a message

```
[Fri Nov 20 15:15:04.274304 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 7656:tid 139998747531136] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/5.0.21 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 20 15:15:04.274334 2015] [core:notice] [pid 7656:tid 139998747531136] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Conf:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/adminuser/hroot>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted

</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.hroot.ncl.ac.uk

    # Tell Apache and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    DocumentRoot /home/adminuser/hroot/

    PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby

    # Relax Apache security settings
    <Directory /home/adminuser/hroot>
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
      # Uncomment this if you're on Apache > 2.4:
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am now getting this message in the log file.

```
App 11778 stderr:      Trying next mirror...
App 11778 stderr:      Could not download https://s3.amazonaws.com/phusion-passenger/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.0.21/rubyext-ruby-2.1.2-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
App 11778 stderr:  --> Continuing without passenger_native_support.so.
App 11778 stdout:
[ 2015-11-24 13:04:47.5518 11693/7fdca9f4e700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/adminuser/hroot: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: eee6139e
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-EzX9GD.html
  Message from application: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

After trying the link you suggested i am getting this error message:

[ 2015-11-24 14:50:58.1887 15008/7efc7eab5700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /hroot/hroot: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: d5e32def
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-33KRJ9.html
  Message from application: /hroot/hroot/config/application.rb:23: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/hroot/hroot/config/application.rb:23: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/hroot/hroot/config/application.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting '}'
... 'Deutsch (de)', :fr => 'FranÃ§ais (fr)'}
...                               ^ (SyntaxError)
  /hroot/hroot/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
  /hroot/hroot/config/environment.rb:2:in`'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in`block in '
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in`initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in`'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `eval'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in`preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in`'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `'

Comment: Its difficult to guide unless we know what steps you have followed and what you have tried so far. If you want some tutorial on this I love this blog https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6

Comment: Thanks @PardeepDhingra I am following the instructions on this [link](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/ruby/) after reading the blog it states something about having httpd installed which i don't have. I am running ubuntu 14.4 LTS.

Comment: Can you paste your confing file and how you have loaded passenger module in apache.conf

Comment: Apache and httpd both are same if you have apache installed its fine.

Comment: Your directoy url is wrong. It should point to public folder of your application.

Comment: Apologies i have modfied the code sense then the code i am running now as below:

Comment: You mean your url is correct and you are having DocumentRoot and Multiviews too and still its not working?

Comment: I am very sorry this is an old code. How can paste my code in the comment. It's characters too long! Sorry.

Comment: Update your post instead of putting here in comment.

Comment: this should point to public folder `/home/adminuser/hroot/public`

Comment: @PardeepDhingra Pointing to this directory i get the above error message in the log file.

Comment: Please read answe of user : user2997993 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061774/cannot-load-such-file-bundler-setup-loaderror

Comment: @PardeepDhingra I am getting the above error message now? Many Thanks for your help

Comment: @PardeepDhingra could kindly advise on this issue. many thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739836/invalid-multibyte-char-us-ascii-with-rails-and-ruby-1-9